# Getting Admin Product Search to Ignore Special Characters in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have a client who is wanting the product search in the admin area to ignore the fact that there are special characters in the product names.

For example, they have a lot of products listed with the word “kings” or the word “king’s” with an apostrophe - both used correctly grammatically depending on the product.

What they want to be able to do is search for “kings” on the admin area and all products called “kings” and “king’s” appear - rather than just “kings” as it does by default.

They have the same problem with “remy” and “r.e.m.y” where, when searching for “remy” the search needs to ignore the fact that there are “.” In the name.

Opencart Version 2.3.0.2

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look, if you have expirience you can do it easily, just find `search query` in Opencart and replace all special symbols with empty string, check this example if you have r.e.m.y in your database table blog, title column with value 'r.e.m.y, then this query will return you record

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE title = replace(title,'.','') = 'remy'
```

Check image for example:

[image]

Example is for points '.' only but you can do replace and for other special symbols.

Let me show you where to find this query:

1. First you can see link is catalog/product, so your controller is 
   in `admin/catalog/product`, when u type something in "title" input, it send GET parameter `&filter_name` to this controller. You can check the controller for that filter, see:

   `protected function getList() {
       if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
           $filter_name = $this->request->get['filter_name'];
       } else {
           $filter_name = null;
       }`

   Here it check for this GET parameter and set it to variable `$filter_name`, then bellow the code it send this variable to model:

   ```
   $filter_data = array(
       'filter_name'     => $filter_name,
       'filter_model'    => $filter_model,
       'filter_price'    => $filter_price,
       'filter_quantity' => $filter_quantity,
       'filter_status'   => $filter_status,
       'filter_image'    => $filter_image,
       'sort'            => $sort,
       'order'           => $order,
       'start'           => ($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin'),
       'limit'           => $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')
   );
   ```

   `$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);`

It set array with variables then u call `$this->model->catalog->product->getTotalProducts`, so there is query u need:

```
public function getTotalProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)";

    $sql .= " WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
        $sql .= " AND pd.name LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_model'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.model LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_model']) . "%'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_price']) && !is_null($data['filter_price'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.price LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_price']) . "%'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_quantity']) && !is_null($data['filter_quantity'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.quantity = '" . (int)$data['filter_quantity'] . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_status']) && !is_null($data['filter_status'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.status = '" . (int)$data['filter_status'] . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_image']) && !is_null($data['filter_image'])) {
        if ($data['filter_image'] == 1) {
            $sql .= " AND (p.image IS NOT NULL AND p.image <> '' AND p.image <> 'no_image.png')";
        } else {
            $sql .= " AND (p.image IS NULL OR p.image = '' OR p.image = 'no_image.png')";
        }
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->row['total'];
}
```

If you don't have expirience with Opencart it will be not so easy, but it's possible.

**One hint:** u can use your own query if this parameter is set (if-else) :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply - that's what I've been trying to do but I'm struggling to find the search query in Opencart. That's where I'm getting stuck.